# Is it necessary to learn nodejs before learning angularjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am learning angularjs, but which ever the sample demo i download for better understand the angularjs, they have used nodejs too. 
Ex: In this blog:
http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/11/angularjs-example-applications.html
 All the examples, include nodejs as backend.

1. Is it necessary to learn nodejs.
2. The yeoman and other supporting tools like bower, grunt make use of nodejs.
   but i feel difficult to learn two sets of programming, as i know PHP to some extent.
3. Can i use these yeoman, bower and grunt without nodejs and use php as my backend. If so, please provide the demo sample link having php as backend.

Comment: Node.js is just an environment to run JavaScript on the server. It provides a library with additional functions/modules do do typical server stuff that you can't to with "plain" JavaScript. It is, however, not a different programming language.

Comment: Yeah, I'd even say it's better to learn nodejs **instead** of learning angularjs. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. No, node.js is more of a back-end technology and get help you get a server up and running quickly to serve up your examples, Angular is front-end framework. You can get an Angular app up and running without node.
2. Yeoman, Grunt, and Bower help take a lot of the "grunt-work" out of bootstrapping web applications. They help with the build process, downloading dependencies, etc. but:

   a. You don't need them to learn Angular

   b. They're not languages. PHP and JS are languages.
3. You'll need node.js to run grunt, yeoman, and bower.

I'm sure you can serve a webpage off PHP and learn Angular just fine, but keep in mind that Angular is a JavaScript framework. Node.js, grunt, yeoman, bower are all rooted in JS, so the deeper you dive with JS and those tools, the better you'll be able to understand Angular and what goes on under the hood.

Comment: AngularJS is a MVC framework and helps to reduce the workload in big way. This has nothing to do with server-side script. I advise you to learn AngularJS on its own without connecting it with any server-side script. 'AngularJS' by Brad Green is a very good book for beginner as well as advanced studies.

Answer (score 0):

1. no
2. you don't need yeoman to learn angularjs or nodejs
3. Nodejs is just the running environment for yeoman, bower, grunt. You don't need to learn nodejs to learn about them. Just install nodejs and forget.

Comment: Thanks dude, you made me clear, 'If so, please provide the demo sample link having php as backend.' ? Can you please post some links with php as background. One more doubt, after running the npm it  opens the link in browser as http://localhost:8000:/index.html#, can i give a meaningful url like http://foodme/index.html#

Answer (score 0):

Nope. NodeJS and AngularJS are different frameworks which are independent of each other.

AngularJS is a frontend framework which can use any suitable backend framework including PHP.

Just install NodeJS to install angular dependencies like Yeoman, bower, and grunt and you're good to go doing some Angular work without worrying about NodeJS.